# Для группы строк дата в одной ячейке. Фильтр по дате

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица подобной этой:

[image: Таблица]

Как сделать фильтрацию по дате так, чтобы при фильтрации  отображались все значения в столбце "События" для этой даты?

Comment: продублировать дату в пустые ячейки

Comment: Если не хочется ВИДЕТЬ продублированные данные - условным форматированием по условию "=R[-1]С" сделать шрифт белым по белому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доп. столбец с датами в каждой строке. 
Например, столбец С. Фильтр по этому столбцу.
Формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A3>0;A3;C2)
```

'--------------------------

Можно обойтись без доп. столбца, быстро заполнив пустые ячейки недостающими значениями.

Выделить диапазон с датами (без "шапки" таблицы, только даты и пустые ячейки).

После этого жмем *Ctrl+G,  Выделить-Пустые_ячейки-ОК*.

Не снимая выделения, пишем = (знак "равно") и выделяем ячейку с датой в верхней строке. Фактически в первую выделенную пустую ячейку запиcываем формулу (*=A3*)

Последнее действие - жмем *Ctrl+Enter* - все пустые ячейки выделенного диапазона заполнятся датами.